# SQL returns null when like criteria contains more than one character

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm using SQL to try and return a subset of entries from a table with 3.5m rows using PGAdmin. The following code returns 131,970 rows:

```
SELECT 
  orgs.org_name, 
  orgs.org_oid
FROM 
  public.orgs
WHER
  org_name LIKE 'L%'
ORDER BY
  orgs.org_name ASC
```

However, once I add more characters into the LIKE criteria, PGAdmin returns no data at all:

```
SELECT 
  orgs.org_name, 
  orgs.org_oid
FROM 
  public.orgs
WHER
  org_name LIKE 'Lo%'
ORDER BY
  orgs.org_name ASC
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with my SQL, but I'm getting no error messages from PGAdmin to indicate that memory or anything else might be the problem.

I'm running on a mac OS X 10.8 using PGAdmin 1.16.0 and Postgres 9.2

Comment: Are there any organizations with names starting with 'Lo'?  I bet there aren't...

Comment: @woodbine, i think had you searched a bit on Google you could have solve the question by yourself. There's nothing wrong with your query. And the reason you are not getting any data from your second query is because there is no record in column orgs.org_name that starts with 'Lo'.

Answer (score 2):

Try using lower keyword for the data:

```
SELECT 
  orgs.org_name, 
  orgs.org_oid
FROM 
  public.orgs
WHER
  lower(org_name) LIKE 'lo%'
ORDER BY
  orgs.org_name ASC
```

Comment: Everything in org_name is uppercase, so I'm feeling a bit stupid. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

If you sure in `orgs` you have names start with 'Lo', try to use `UPPER` as below:

```
SELECT 
  orgs.org_name, 
  orgs.org_oid
FROM 
  public.orgs
WHERE
  UPPER(org_name) LIKE 'LO%'
ORDER BY
  orgs.org_name ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ilike` to filter without case sensitivity:

```
SELECT orgs.org_name, orgs.org_oid FROM public.orgs
WHERE
UPPER(org_name) ILIKE 'LO%' --OR ILIKE 'lo%' (same thing)
```